# UINavigationBar BarTintColor not working with RGB Values

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I spent about an hour trying to figure out why my BarTintColor wasn't changing in a UINavigation bar. I guess that you cannot use RGB to set the BarTintColor? Is there a workaround for this? I want to be able to control the color.

UPDATE:

OK kambla helped me a lot. I put the following in my app delegate at the tail end of of "applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

```
  NSUInteger r = 228, g = 228, b = 228;
  UIColor *color =
      [UIColor colorWithRed:r / 255.0 green:g / 255.0 blue:b / 255.0 alpha:0];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:color];

  return YES;
```

I confirmed that the code is executing. But the tint color on my navigation bars do not change?

Comment: Show your code and read the `UIColor` docs so you understand the values it expects.

Comment: `alpha:0` means that you create a fully transparent color (i.e. invisible). Note that in my answer I use the alpha value `1.0` (fully opaque / non-transparent).

Comment: My error. I tried alpha 1.0 and it is the same. Nothing changes. I am stumped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to divide your RGB values by `255.0` because `UIColor` expects values in `0.0-1.0` range:

```
NSUInteger r = 127, g = 127, b = 127;
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Don't assume a problem exists until you see it. OP hasn't posted any relevant code.

Comment: I agree with you. But it's a rather common pitfall.